# Can AUTO_CLOSE be set OFF by default on SQL Express?

Tags: sql-server

I have just discovered that the AUTO_CLOSE option is always set to ON for databases created on SQL Express and is always set to OFF for databases created on full versions of SQL Server.  I used the command `CREATE DATABASE [test]`

This is definitely worthy of note as it is well documented that AUTO_CLOSE should always be OFF except in some very rare cases.

Is there a way to set the server defaults to always create databases with a certain set of options, including AUTO_CLOSE=OFF ?

Also is there a documented list anywhere of the default options for each version of SQL Server, especially the major differences like this one between Express and Full?

Comment: These defaults are taken from the `model` system database. When you create a new database, essentially, `model` is copied and dolled up as new instance, so whatever options you like as defaults should be set there. I have never seen any instance of SQL Server (including Express editions) where `model` has `AUTO_CLOSE` to `ON` after a clean install, but this may be a change between versions.

Comment: Thanks.  But I fear there is a specific difference with Express... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2008/02/22/understanding-sql-express-behavior-idle-time-resource-usage-auto_close-and-user-instances/

Comment: Oh, that's very sneaky! When you create the database through SSMS, it will take pains to copy the properties over from `model`, so the database will still have `AUTO_CLOSE` set to `OFF` -- explaining why I've never seen this (that and restoring backups). When you issue a `CREATE DATABASE` statement on your own, Express will set the database to auto-close regardless of how `model` is configured. I did not know that. (It's also a grandiose misfeature, as far as I'm concerned, but that's another matter.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to set the server defaults to always create databases with a certain set of options, including AUTO_CLOSE=OFF ?

whenever you create a new DB,it uses model db as template .Below are the options which can be changed and which can't be

```
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
|        Database option        |         Default value          | Can be modified |
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
| ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION      | OFF                            | Yes             |
| ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT             | OFF                            | Yes             |
| ANSI_NULLS                    | OFF                            | Yes             |
| ANSI_PADDING                  | OFF                            | Yes             |
| ANSI_WARNINGS                 | OFF                            | Yes             |
| ARITHABORT                    | OFF                            | Yes             |
| AUTO_CLOSE                    | OFF                            | Yes             |
| AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS        | ON                             | Yes             |
| AUTO_SHRINK                   | OFF                            | Yes             |
| AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS        | ON                             | Yes             |
| AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC  | OFF                            | Yes             |
| CHANGE_TRACKING               | OFF                            | No              |
| CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL       | OFF                            | Yes             |
| CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT        | OFF                            | Yes             |
| CURSOR_DEFAULT                | GLOBAL                         | Yes             |
| Database Availability Options | ONLINE                         | No              |
|                               |                                |                 |
|                               | MULTI_USER                     | Yes             |
|                               |                                |                 |
|                               | READ_WRITE                     | Yes             |
| DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION | OFF                            | Yes             |
| DB_CHAINING                   | OFF                            | No              |
| ENCRYPTION                    | OFF                            | No              |
| NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT            | OFF                            | Yes             |
| PAGE_VERIFY                   | CHECKSUM                       | Yes             |
| PARAMETERIZATION              | SIMPLE                         | Yes             |
| QUOTED_IDENTIFIER             | OFF                            | Yes             |
| READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT       | OFF                            | Yes             |
| RECOVERY                      | Depends on SQL Server edition1 | Yes             |
| RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS            | OFF                            | Yes             |
| Service Broker Options        | DISABLE_BROKER                 | No              |
| TRUSTWORTHY                   | OFF                            | No              |
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
```

> is there a documented list anywhere of the default options for each version of SQL Server

You can look at this link for extensive details :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

As per my understanding,there will be no differences in default options of databases between editions.

Comment: Thanks.  But it appears there is a difference with express...
.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2008/02/22/understanding-sql-express-behavior-idle-time-resource-usage-auto_close-and-user-instances/
.
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57270/autoclose-property-resets-to-true-after-attaching-db-even-if-model-is-set-to-fal
.
http://sqlmag.com/blog/worst-practice-allowing-autoclose-sql-server-databases

Comment: those links doesn't tell about default options,which won't be different between editions.